# Android kotlin retrofit DefaultDispatcher-worker-1, SLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit, kotlin-coroutines

I am getting a lisst from api using retrofit inside viewModelScope but I am getting this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.example.assignment4, PID: 3654
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed
    .
    .
    .
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: Chain validation failed
    .
    .
    .
     Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: Certificate expired at Mon Jun 26 04:57:13 GMT+05:30 2023 (compared to Thu Jun 29 18:49:02 GMT+05:30 2023)
```

This is my coroutine

```
viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    val response = ServiceGenerator.api.getCharacters()

    if(response.isSuccessful) {
        characterList.value = response.body()
        for(character in response.body()!!) {
            Log.e(TAG, character.toString())
        }
        adapter.getList(characterList.value!!)
    }
    else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed")
    }
}
```

Retrofit

```
val api = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .build()
        .create(ApiService::class.java)
```

```
interface ApiService {

    @GET("/")
    suspend fun getCharacters(): Response<List<Character>>
}
```

I have checked for the date issue but date fine.
What is the problem? How should I fix it?

Comment: `SSLHandshakeException: Chain validation failed` means that the SSL cert for the endpoint you're trying to access isn't valid. In this particular case it even tells you why: It's expired.